# Sending variables through post android using URLEncoding

Tags: php, android, post, url-encoding

I'm trying to send post variables through UrlEncoding from android to php page which is working for me if i send one variable only. So how to encode more than one variable, i've tried some on my own.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        String link = "http://URL.php";
        String name = params[0];
        String email = params[1];
        String phone = params[2];
        String pass = params[3];
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("phone", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(phone, "UTF-8");
        String data1 = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8");
        String data2 = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
        String data3 = URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");
        URL url = new URL(link);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.write(data1);
        wr.write(data2);
        wr.write(data3);
        wr.flush();
```

This is doing the job but only first variable is accessible through php side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only able to access the first variable because, you are not appending each parameter with `&`. You could use this method to get a parameter string.

```
public String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");
            try {
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                result.append("=");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```

You can get a parameter string like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("phone",phone);
params.put("email",email);
params.put("name",name);
params.put("pass",pass);
String paramString = getPostDataString(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();
wr.write(data1);
wr.flush();
wr.write(data2);
wr.flush();
wr.write(data3);
wr.flush();
```